# QGIS Download Size

Tags: qgis, installation, download

I am planning to download the latest QGIS (2.18) to have a play and see what the fuss is about.

I have found the [downloads page](http://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html) on the QGIS website  which includes the installer I think I need - *QGIS Standalone Installer Version 2.18 (64 bit)* - however the filesize seems a little small to me at ~350mb.  (I had expected 1.5gb-2gb)

I have very very slow internet and am hesitant to download something that may turn out to be a web installer that then downloads the different software components as part of the install.  I would prefer something where I can download the full package and be able to reinstall as required without having to re-download.

Is the *QGIS Standalone Installer Version 2.18 (64 bit)* the full install file, or is there another full package I should download instead?

I'm running Windows 10 64 bit.

Comment: Just for completeness, you seem to look for a Windows OS download.

Comment: @AndreJ correct

Comment: Indeed it contains the full install, just one of the **many** beauties of QGIS ;)

Comment: @Joseph you would not be so exited if you had a poor internet connection ...

Comment: @AndreJ - True, I guess I'm fortunate that my place of work does have decent connections =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what full package means. QGIS standalone comes with all dependencies required to work properly with its functions available on that version. QGIS standalone installer has a small file size because other functions (plugins) can be downloaded from inside QGIS when you need them. It is different from other commercial software, such as ArcGIS, that you install everything onetime including the extensions, then you just activate the software and extension based on license level.

If you need more advanced installation, you can download OSGeo4W installer, in which you can select QGIS, GRASS, and SAGA, and any additional software. But you will notice when you download OSGeo4W installer that it has also small file size, because it downloads everything from inside the installer. In this case, it is recommended to be connected to the internet, and I think in your case it will take long time because the internet is slow.

*Regarding Plugins:*

If the plugins were downloaded from the Plugin manager, it will be difficult to save them on a separate folder later. So the best way to keep the plugins on a separate folder is to download them separately from [QGIS Python Plugins Repository](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/popular/). Then extract the plugin to `C:\users\<username>\.qgis2\python\plugins`. For example, if you want to download Profile tool plugin:

1. Select the plugin that you want, and click on details

[image]

2. Go to Latest stable version:

[image]

3. Click on Download.

[image]

4. The size of profiletool-3.7.1.zip that was downloaded is just `33kb`. You can keep the downloaded plugins on a separate external folder to use them later.

The downside of this method that you need to update the plugins manually following the same process. But from the Plugin manager inside QGIS, you just receive a notice of which plugins need to be updated and they can be updated easily.

The size of the downloaded plugins are very small from kilobytes to megabyte depending on the number of plugins you download.

Comment: With the OSGEO4W installer, you can deselect GRASS, orfeotoolbox and SAGA if you don't need those, and save all to a separate folder from where to install without internet connection at any time. The download amount will be much smaller than using the standalone installer.

Comment: I agree with you, I just give him an option that he can select or deselect any software he wants or does not want, and for sure when he deselects any software, the size will be reduced.

Comment: If plugins are downloaded internally, are these saved somewhere so a redownload isn't required if I reinstall?

Comment: It depends whether the plugins are core plugins or external plugins. You can refer to this link https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins.html. If the plugins are core plugins, it will be uninstalled with uninstalling QGIS, but with external plugins, the plugins may still exist, however, I am not sure about that.

Comment: Yes, external python plugins will be kept even after uninstalling, in folder `C:\users\<username>\.qgis2\python\plugins\`. But these are **not** downloaded internally, only on user demand.

Comment: @AndreJ and @ ahmadhanb just wanting to clarify a couple of things - 1) are plugins saveable (even manually - ie copying the folder in Explorer, then copying back in after a reinstall) so I don't have to re-download them, and 2) how big are the plugins typically - can they be huge?

Comment: for 1): yes, exactly like that, but no need to copy back because they won't be deleted, for 2): my current plugins are between 6,5MB and 79kB, so really no problem of size.

Comment: I updated my answer just in case you need to download the plugins manually.

Comment: ahmadhanb and @AndreJ thanks for the updates and extra info, that's what I want to know.  Am downloading now

Comment: @Midavalo You are welcome. Enjoy QGISing. AndreJ thanks also for your support.

Answer (score 7):

It's An Offline Install :

**- Downloaded version :**
[image]

**Offline Install :**

[image]

**Size Of Folder after install** : (1.5 Go)

[image]

**Installed Packages**

[image]

Comment: When running the setup, make sure **not** to select the sample data, which will to be downloaded separately during setup. Apart from that, the installer runs truly offline. Plugins (except core) have to be downloaded separately on demand, but have small size.